# What is set S for which for any y, x, will cause no x to exist in set S

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, predicate-logic

My apologies beforehand if the question is worded poorly because I've been stumped on the exact meaning of this question for awhile. This was the best way I could phrase it.

I've been stuck in a predicate logic question written as such:

`Come up with a model S for which domain is 0, 1.`
`∀y (∀x.S(y, x) -> ¬∃x.S(y, x))`

To my interpretation, the common English wording is:

Come up with a set S for which, for any y, any x implies there does not exist an x.

Now it seems to me that the only set that can always satisfy this condition seems to be the empty set {}.

Rough ideas here:

Initially I have rewritten it to be:

`∀y (¬∀x.S(y, x) v ¬∃x.S(y, x))`

And my initial thought is:

S = {(0,0),(1,1)}

However, it does not seem to satisfy the first condition and second condition. If y = 0 and x = 0, then clearly there exists an x that matches y.

The empty set seems like the only set that works. However, would there more suitable sets for this predicate logic question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I misread the question to be $((\forall y ..) \rightarrow ..)$ instead of $\forall y ( .. \rightarrow ..)$. In this case, the question says,

Pick any $y \in \{ 0 , 1 \}$. Then:
if for some $x \in \{ 0, 1 \} \;, (y,x) \in S \Rightarrow (y, \bar{x} ) \notin S$.

So yeah $\{(0,0) \}$ works and so do many other sets.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding so quickly, although my apologies I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the context of your answer. Based on my current understanding, it seems like you are also suggesting that the empty set is the only set that would work. Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you, that matches with my thoughts also. I'll see if anyone wants to suggest otherwise but I agree this seems to be the only valid solution.

Comment: Thank you Malice, although 2 questions 1) if x = 0 and y = 0, would we not have found a match and hence rendered ∀¬(,)) false 2) while empty set is not necessarily the only valid solution, is it also a solution? And again so sorry if I'm getting my logics wrong I've been stuck on this for awhile

Comment: @RosaryLightningX - The empty set is also a solution, yes. We don't need to satisfy $\forall x\neg S(y,x)$; we only need to satisfy *either* that *or* $\exists x\neg S(y,x)$. Implications are not conjunctions.

Comment: Thank you very much!